# Spiking CPU frequency on Thinkpad X220 with i5-2540M Processor, Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, intel, cpu, thinkpad, frequency

I encounter a strange behavior on my laptop (Thinkpad X220, Intel i5-2540M CPU). I recently switched from Windows 7 to Ubuntu 20.04, and I was hoping that everything would just perfectly work. After just starting my computer, everything just work fine.

But, sometimes everything drastically slows down on my screen, and my mouse lags very much (looks like 1 FPS). Everything (CPU, RAM usage, etc.) is fine, except the CPU frequency. It spikes a lot.

Since my computer worked just perfectly when I was running Windows, I suppose it could be related to the Linux drivers and the power and frequency management tools.

Did anyone encounter the same behavior running Ubuntu or any other Linux distro on this Thinkpad?

Currently, my computer uses the `intel_pstat` driver in active mode but without the `Harware Managed P-states (HWP)` function available. Should I run it in passive mode (intel_cpufreq)? Or use the `acpi-cpufreq` driver instead?

Other questions :

- Would you know some tools that would allow me to precisely look at my CPU frequency?
- Do you know where I could my processor Model Specific Registers (MSR) to help me to configure my driver settings?

Answer (score 0):

> And when it begins, the CPU frequency is driving mad, going up and
> done quickly, without stabilizing.

Yes, this is normal.

> I suppose it could be related to the linux drivers and the power and
> frequency management tools. Do you think it could be related ?

Don't know yet.

> Currently, my computer uses the intel_pstat driver in active mode but
> without the "Harware Managed P-states (HWP)" function available.
> Should I run it in passive mode (intel_cpufreq) ? Or even use the
> acpi-cpufreq driver instead ?

Your processor does not have HWP.
Yes, you should try both intel_cpufreq and acpi-cpufreq.
You should also try limiting your maximum CPU frequency with the current intel_pstate driver, as a test. Do:

```
$ echo 75 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/max_perf_pct
```

adjust the 75 up or down as required.

> Would you know some tools that would allow me to precisely look at my
> CPU frequency ?

I prefer turbostat, (I forget which package, maybe linux-tools-common and/or linux-tools-5.4.0-26 (or whatever kernel version)) and it is the only tool that upstream escalations will accept as authoritative. Myself, I run this command almost always:

```
~$ sudo turbostat --Summary --quiet --show Busy%,Bzy_MHz,PkgTmp,PkgWatt,GFXWatt,IRQ --interval 6
Busy%   Bzy_MHz IRQ     PkgTmp  PkgWatt GFXWatt
0.01    3568    194     30      1.81    0.00
0.01    3700    112     30      1.76    0.00
```

And never use a short interval. Often users do not seem to realize that idle CPUs can go into deep idle states for multiple seconds at a time, and they wake them just to sample stuff.

> Do you know where I could my processor Model Specific Registers (MSR)
> to help me to configure my driver settings ?

If you want to start messing with the MSRs yourself, then you need to use the several thousand pages [Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/intel-sdm.html). It is very difficult to follow and to find the appropriate pages for your specific model of CPU. I wouldn't go there just yet.